# Smarty - Check if 2 first characters are xx

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

In Smarty, i need to check if an id starts with 2 characters. Here is my actual code :

```
 {if !$product.add_to_cart_url}{/if}
              {if $product->quantity < 2}disabled
              {elseif (($product->id_category_default)|strstr:"11") && ($product->quantity < 10) }disabled
              {elseif (($product->id_category_default)|strstr:"15") && ($product->quantity < 10) }disabled
              {elseif (($product->id_category_default)|strstr:"16") && ($product->quantity < 10) }disabled
              {else}
{/if}
```

But it gives me categories who contains "15" for example. I just need it to give me categories starting with "15" like 151111, 151112, 151113 etc ... not 111523.

Any idea ?
Thank you guys !

Comment: `$product->id_category_default|substr:0:2`

Comment: In addition to @MarkusZeller's answer, may I also suggest that you convert this check into a method on your `$product` class. Templates should contain as little low-level code as possible.